# Is the function invertible?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1q,&x\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }x=\frac{p}q\text{ in lowest terms}\\
0,&x\notin\Bbb Q\;.
\end{cases}$$

Is the function $f|_D$  invertible? If so, describe its inverse concisely.

Here $$D=\{\sqrt{2}\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

I think the function is invertible because the function $f|_D$ is a one-to-one function.

Can some one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean $D = \{\sqrt{2}\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: Yes @N.F.Taussig

Comment: You haven’t actually told us what your function $f|_D$ is.

Comment: f|D is the domain of f such that f is one to one and onto @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Abhi: That’s not correct: $D$ is the domain of the function $f|_D$. It happens to be true that $f|_D$ is one-to-one, but you haven’t actually told us what function it is. What are $f|_D\left(\frac15\right)$ and $f|_D(\sqrt2)$, say?

Comment: @Abhi: You made some errors in your edits; I’ve corrected them. You appear to have some serious misunderstandings. $\{\sqrt2\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ is $D$, not $f|_D$. $f|_D$ is the function; $D$ is its domain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sorry for the confusion.  f|d is the is a function that is is simultaneously one-to-one and onto the range of f.

Comment: @Abhi: Yes, that’s correct. And the range is $R=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$, so all you have to do is describe the function $$(f|_D)^{-1}:R\to D\;.$$

Comment: @Abhi: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f|_D: D\to A$ is a bijection where $A=\{{0}\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ such that $f|_D^{-1}=g$ where $g: A \to D$ such that $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1n,&x\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }x=\frac{1}n\text{ in lowest terms}\\
\sqrt{2},&x=0\ 
\end{cases}$$